# Collectd in InfluxDB2.0

Tags: telegraf, collectd, influxdb-2

I want to deploy influxDB with collectd.
For previous version ie 1.8 of influxDB it was supported.
Do we have support for collectd in the latest version of influxdb i.e 2.0?

Answer (score 6):

This functionality was moved to telegraf. in `/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf` you have to define a collectd input and an influxdb output, then it works. I haven't found an example so I had to piece it together from different sources of documentation:

```
[agent]
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = false
[[inputs.socket_listener]]
  service_address = "udp://:25826"
  data_format = "collectd"
  collectd_auth_file = "/etc/collectd/collectd.auth"
  collectd_security_level = "encrypt"
  collectd_typesdb = ["/usr/share/collectd_types.db"]
  collectd_parse_multivalue = "split"
[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
 urls = ["http://influxdb:8086"]
 token = "$DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN"
 organization = "$DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG"
 bucket = "$DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET"
```